# str() prints first no matter the order in R

Tags: r, function, csv

I am writing a function that would give the dim() and str() of a given dataset.

```
JustfunFun <- function(.csv) {
  csv <- read.csv(.csv)
  dimVal <- dim(csv)
  print("The dimension of the dataset is:")
  strVal <- str(csv)
  print("The structute of the dataset is:")
  headVal <- head(csv)
  return(list(dimVal, strVal, headVal))
}
```

Ideally, the output must have the dimension first, the structure second and then the head of dataset.

But the output is as follows:

```
> JustfunFun("tips.csv")
[1] "The dimension of the dataset is:"
'data.frame':   244 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ obs    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ totbill: num  17 10.3 21 23.7 24.6 ...
 $ tip    : num  1.01 1.66 3.5 3.31 3.61 4.71 2 3.12 1.96 3.23 ...
 $ sex    : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ smoker : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ day    : Factor w/ 4 levels "Fri","Sat","Sun",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ time   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Day","Night": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ size   : int  2 3 3 2 4 4 2 4 2 2 ...
[1] "The structute of the dataset is:"
[1] "The head of the dataset is:"
[[1]]
[1] 244   8

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
  obs totbill  tip sex smoker day  time size
1   1   16.99 1.01   F     No Sun Night    2
2   2   10.34 1.66   M     No Sun Night    3
3   3   21.01 3.50   M     No Sun Night    3
4   4   23.68 3.31   M     No Sun Night    2
5   5   24.59 3.61   F     No Sun Night    4
6   6   25.29 4.71   M     No Sun Night    4

>
```

How do I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str`, like `print` does not return anything. You can see the last line of `utils:::str.default`. The easiest way to see this is try to nest a `str` ( ie. `str(str(mtcars))` ).

This function should print the way you want, AND store the data.

```
JustfunFun <- function(.csv) {
    csv <- read.csv(.csv)
    dimVal <- dim(csv)
    print("The dimension of the dataset is:")
    print(dimVal)
    print("The structute of the dataset is:")
    strVal <- utils:::capture.output(str(csv))
    print(strVal)
    print(head(csv))
    return(invisible(list(dimVal, strVal, head(csv))))
}
```

Example:

```
write.csv(mtcars, "mtcars.csv", row.names = FALSE)
a <- JustfunFun("mtcars.csv")
```

Result:

```
[1] "The dimension of the dataset is:"
[1] 32 11
[1] "The structute of the dataset is:"
[1] "'data.frame':\t32 obs. of  11 variables:"                          
[2] " $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ..."  
[3] " $ cyl : int  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ..."                            
[4] " $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ..."                            
[5] " $ hp  : int  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ..."           
[6] " $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ..."
[7] " $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ..."                       
[8] " $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ..."                           
[9] " $ vs  : int  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ..."                            
[10] " $ am  : int  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ..."                            
[11] " $ gear: int  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ..."                            
[12] " $ carb: int  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ..."  
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

str(a)
 $ : int [1:2] 32 11
 $ : chr [1:12] "'data.frame':\t32 obs. of  11 variables:" " $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ..." " $ cyl : int  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ..." " $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ..." ...
 $ :'data.frame':   6 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ mpg : num [1:6] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1
  ..$ cyl : int [1:6] 6 6 4 6 8 6
  ..$ disp: num [1:6] 160 160 108 258 360 225
  ..$ hp  : int [1:6] 110 110 93 110 175 105
  ..$ drat: num [1:6] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76
  ..$ wt  : num [1:6] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
  ..$ qsec: num [1:6] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
  ..$ vs  : int [1:6] 0 0 1 1 0 1
  ..$ am  : int [1:6] 1 1 1 0 0 0
  ..$ gear: int [1:6] 4 4 4 3 3 3
  ..$ carb: int [1:6] 4 4 1 1 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything that you have written in your function is correct except the fact that  you need to capture the `str`by command `capture.output`. So, below is the function that you are looking for:

```
JustfunFun <- function(.csv) {
  csv <- read.csv(.csv)
  dimVal <- dim(csv)
  strVal <- capture.output(str(csv))
  headVal <- head(csv)
  return(list("The dimension of the dataset is:" =  dimVal, 
              "The structute of the dataset is:" =  strVal, 
              headVal))
}
```

Cheers & happy R Coding

Answer (score -1):

If you are only interested in displaying the result without storing it, you could write a function that does not return anything but print the dimensions, the structure and the head of the data. The following code seems to do the trick.

```
# Simulation of the data
dat <- data.frame(obs=1:100,totbill=round(100*runif(100)),sex=sample(c("F","M"),100,replace=TRUE))

# Function
dim.str.head <- function(dat){
    print("The dimension of the dataset is:")
    print(dim(dat))
    print("The structure of the dataset is:")
    print(str(dat))
    print("The first observations look like this:")
    head(dat)
}

# Try the function
dim.str.head(dat)
```

Comment: The function takes a csv file as an input. Your solution doesn't seem to do that. I don't need an alternative function to do the same work, I want an workaround to get the desired output.

Comment: The input does not matter much (you get a data frame out of the read.csv() step anyway) and the idea was to provide a code that anyone could run, in compliance with the guidelines of SO. Sorry you didn't like it.

Comment: Your answer gave an insight. Please have a look at the above two answers, that is what I wanted.